# How can i check request type in the IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

How can i check request type for POST/GET in the IIS7 by Url Rewrite->Inbound Rule->Condition?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: It seems i need to check `{REQUEST_METHOD}`. It is works in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i need to check {REQUEST_METHOD}. It is works in my case.